# Do academics charge for talks at student societies? As a PhD student, should I ask for some honorarium when giving a talk at a student society?

Tags: phd, presentation

I am a first year PhD student. I have been invited to give a talk at a student society in my own university (so no travel costs, etc). I am wondering whether I should ask for a small fee when giving the talk. Some points:

- I have been an organiser at other student societies, and generally we wouldn't pay when professors gave a talk with us, but we would invite them to dinner ([prepandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19)). There was someone who asked to be paid (she said she always charges) and we agreed (she is a public figure).
- Obviously it may seem a bit arrogant that I (only a PhD student) ask for a fee, but during my undergraduate studies I gave quite a few student talks / seminars for other students (for free), so I have become a bit of a big name on campus, and I believe my talks are good.
- I have been paid by the university when giving a sample lecture about my area of research to prospective students, and also when helping out at other outreach events.
- It's a student society after all (not a conference), so I am not sure it would look particularly great on my CV, especially given that I already have quite a few of these on my CV (albeit I wasn't invited).
- The society is about the *ethics* of X, where X is my field. I have been an advocate of ethical considerations of my field (usually ignored), so I am flattered to have been invited and I genuinely care about this.
- I generally enjoy giving talks.
- But it takes me time, and obviously my research, my teaching, and my personal life also require a lot of time.
- It takes me about 24 hours to prepare a good talk (for example, six evenings). ((Is this way too much time?)).

Should I give the talk? Should I ask for some fee?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't ask for money, in particular not in case of a student society. But if you do, please do not forget that such a fee would likely be taxable income, with all the associated paperwork involved.

Comment: I've never asked for a fee, and I generally decline honoraria if offered.  (When my own institution offers money, I take it.)

Comment: @mlk (and others interested): Your comment about "associated paperwork involved" reminded me of something in Feynman's 1985 book [**Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surely_You%27re_Joking,_Mr._Feynman!), so I got my copy of the book to look it up. What I was thinking of wound up being the entry titled "Thirteen Times" on pp. 256-257. Googling a random phrase in it, I [found a copy of that section on the internet](https://pastebin.com/t3Behfz1).

Comment: At your own university, do not expect to be paid.  One exception: there may be a dinner at a restaurant after the talk, and your check may be covered by the society.

Comment: I appreciate you linking to COVID-19 in case no one had heard about it lol

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That was done in an edit

Comment: Oh lol well then thanks @PeterMortensen

Comment: I did sometimes *pay* to give a talk.... ([this one](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/intro-programmation-sous-Linux.pdf)... in French. I paid the TGV train ticket)

Comment: For conferences I believe it is very rare that invited speakers get paid. Conference dues are always covered for invited speakers. Often hotel and transportation are too, but even that isn't always.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I would suggest to not ask a fee. It's a student society, and having served in the board of one, budget was always tight. Talks by PhDs and professors were always good since students could learn a lot and it was easy to organize and almost everybody was willing to talk about what they were doing, and always with a bottle of wine (or something non-alcoholic where appropriate) as 'payment'.

Regarding spending 24 hours on a talk - that seems like too much for a small gig at the student society. You know your field/research, and you probably have a feeling on the ethics around it, so it should be relatively easy to come up with what you want to say. I'd spend at most four hours on it, for a 30-45 minute talk. Two hours of structuring my contents, and two hours for creating the slides.

[Thanks avid](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/171168/do-academics-charge-for-talks-at-student-societies-as-a-phd-student-should-i-a/171173#comment461575_171173) - For a PhD student, you should take into account your funding and whether you can spend your working hours on this, or if you should do this in your free time.

Comment: For a professor, at least, I would suggest that giving this sort of talk is really part of their 'day job', and so they should account the time spent preparing/delivering it against their usual salary. For a PhD researcher the situation may be a bit more complex, depending on their funding situation.

Comment: @avid you're right - added a bit to the answer.

Comment: You can also perfectly well re-use talks or parts of talks. You don't need a new unique talk every time for this kind of thing. Most professors probably have a few standard outlines ("this is the area I research") and then speak primarily extemporaneously. If you really want a brand new talk, base it on what you're currently studying or researching, since the work of putting together and giving the talk will also double as studying/researching. A really, really good topic for a student group talk is something that you learned previously but have partially forgotten and will need in the future.

Comment: As a grad student I had a presentation that was very much a living document. Every time I'd give a talk, it would come out of the drawer and get updated. Sometimes the updates were substantial, sometimes not, but it was never made from scratch after the first talk. Eventually it became my defense.

Comment: @avid In the US at least, PhD students are typically on a 50% appointment. If that appointment wouldn't cover this, I think it's well within the duties of the 50% studentship that you're technically paying to do, in the same way homework is a PhD student's "day job." But just IMO

Comment: Lucky you to have had a budget. I was the head of the physics students organization at a major university and when we needed money (for the bottle of wine you mentioned, or once a year to visit something), I was kneeling in front of the dean's office to beg for some money (which, I must say, he always gave without nitpicking). If somebody had asked for a fee to talk, I think we would think we misunderstood the request. But then it was in the golden years of French academia where money was not that important to us.

Comment: Treat such things as "service to the community". I'm sure plenty of people have "donated" things to your education.

Comment: @Buffy I imagine in OP's situation I would be willing to talk for free, but it is not a "service to the community".  Instead it is an opportunity to talk about something I am enthused about with an interested audience (maybe I should be paying them!?!).  As such, necessary preparation should be minimal.  If I really thought I needed 24 working hours to prepare the talk, then it would need money.

Comment: @emory, OTOH, preparing for the talk, give you an asset that you can deploy in the future. You have a talk "in the bag" that you can bring out whenever it is useful. The preparation actually improves you in a number of ways that are useful for any academic.

Comment: @Buffy it does improve you but so does exercising or spending time with loved ones.  I feel that OP could forego the 24 hour prep and give the talk extemperaneously (or with minimal prep).  Then OP could collect payment in the form of received constructive criticism.  Maybe we could agree that if the student society wants a smooth, polished, professional talk then they need to pay an honorarium; but they probably don't and OP is thinking too hard on this one.

Answer (score 24):

The questions asks "Do academics charge for talks at student societies". The answer to this is generally no, I've rarely heard of academics charging student societies for talks, especially if they are local.

Note that this is not the same as saying *should* academics charge for their talks, that is a difficult and complex ethical question, but rather that, as a rule, they don't.

You can ask, but I suspect they answer will be that they have no money to pay you.

Answer (score 10):

When I give *local* talks of any kind, I do not at all pretend to charge a fee, nor expect an honorarium, though a dinner (or free parking?) is nice.

When I give non-local *invited* talks, I would expect to have my *expenses* covered, more-or-less (I have to eat *anyway*), but not "make a profit" in money. In some cases there'll be benefits to me from giving the talk, or it promises to be a fun audience, so if my expenses are not completely covered, it's still desirable for me to do.

Yes, if one is in a financially delicate situation, these things loom larger... but I think the academic tradition (in more idealist milieus?) is to not expect to make a profit from telling about your own work.

Answer (score 7):

Given what you’ve told us about yourself, you don’t seem to have the rep to participate in the “cash-for-public-speaking” business.

So, if you asked me for payment, I’d say “no”, I’d think to myself “who does this guy think he is”, and I’d go find another speaker, and I’d never invite you again.

Your local student society might be more generous and forgiving than I am (lots of people are). Do you want to risk it?

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what discipline you are in; that may matter.

As a PhD student, especially in the first year, you should use this kind of invitation to practice giving academic talks of the kind you would give at a conference or as a job talk. In the first year you probably won't have much, but for students it can be an overview of a topic if you don't have research to present.  I know what that would look like in my discipline but not yours.

Because giving academic papers is a part of the work you are training for and will be absolutely necessary in the long run, these are good opportunities as long as you don't let them be a distraction from getting your other work done.

I sometimes invite students on the job market to give practice talks to my undergraduates (if their topic is relevant to the class) and these are really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> I have been paid by the university when giving a sample lecture about
> my area of research to prospective students, and also when helping out
> at other outreach events.

If I read it correctly, it means those events were beyond your duty stated in the contract, so you get paid.

First, ask permission to your university for being paid to give lectures to an external association .
Second, since giving the talk to the Student Association is beyond your duties, you have all the rights to ask for a compensation (talking about ethics ...).
However, your interest in promoting Ethics seems to be very strong, being in itself a reasonable compensation, so I would proceed this way: you can state to the student association that you would charge 200 quids for this talk, but knowing the Students'Associations are on a tight budget, and that budget is better spent on books and beers, ask to convert the 200 quids in one beer or one book (relevant to Ethics of X).

Comment: I don't think the association is external.

Comment: Ugh. Sounds petty (almost extortion) and a good way to get disinvited.

Comment: See, for example: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:George_Bernard_Shaw#Shaw?_"We_have_established_what_you_are,_Madam"

Comment: @Buffy Seems reasonable to me. Give a talk in exchange for a share of the pizza and drinks afterwards, or some token gift like a box of chocolates or a bottle of wine.

Comment: @nick012000, if you don't say a word, you'd almost certainly be invited to a pizza get together anyway. It doesn't need to be a transaction. It can be their gift. A "token gift" that is asked for isn't a gift.

Comment: @Buffy do you mean that what I suggest to do can be misrepresented by a unreferenced crappy quote, possible subject of a dummy meme and so on with plethora of people sharing it over the various social media? Absolutely yes, I agree.

Comment: Ok. Good. So don't do things or get yourself into situations where your actions can be easily misinterpreted to your own disadvantage.

Comment: And please do not follow imaginary advantages and straw-men that led the academia at the point where is now, where work is expected to be performed for free.  Not for-profit does not mean free, asking a fee and proposing to convert it into something else is not extorsion (nor a gift, what is this crap about gifting people? are people monkeys or dogs being tamed?).

Comment: If “quid” is British slang for “pound”, then it’s plural is just “quid”, not “quids”.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are a prominent figure in your field, you might ask whether there is a fee - or even expenses - or anything else but that's what you might ask about, not ask for…